# Magento 2: Adding column to Sales Order grid table

Tags: magento2

Magento2:Adding column to Sales Order grid table.

Comment: are you trying to add a simple text field as the column or a select type ?

Comment: yes i am trying to add simple text fields

Comment: May i know the version number of your Magento 2 and are you trying to add the eav field into the grid column?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2.5 version and i am going to add simple text fields (like: firstname)

Comment: Hello @deep please check the answer and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: okay I am trying this answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add column to `sales_order_grid` database table
2. Add DI configuration to populate the column in `sales_order_grid`
   table with your value
3. Add UI component configuration to display the column in grid

**1.Adding column to sales_order_grid database table**

Columns are added to database tables using `InstallSchema` script.

Just add it to

> `app/code/<your_namespace>/<your_module>/Setup/InstallSchema.php`

file and it will create a column named `affiliate_information`, of type text, with comment “**Affiliate Information**” to `sales_order_grid` during installation.

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid'),
    'affiliate_information',
    [
        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Affiliate Information'
    ]
);
```

After this step, `affiliate_information` column is present in sales_order_grid table, but is remaining empty as it is not mapped to any data source.

**2. DI configuration to populate the column is `sales_order_grid` table.**

to include our table in mentioned insert from select, we have to extend di configuration creating

> `app/code/<Namespace>/<Module>/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

...
    
        
            
                
                    affiliate
                    entity_id
                    order_id
                
            
            
                affiliate.affiliate_information
            
        
    
    ...

After this step, our `affiliate_information` column in `sales_order_grid` table is populated with value from affiliate table each time order is placed. Still, column will exist only in database, and will not be visible in admin panel.

**3. Configure UI grid component to display the column**

Finally, to reflect the column on admin panel grid, we have to extend `sales_order_grid` ui component by adding a ui configuration file in our module.

> app/code///view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<listing ...>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="affiliate_information">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Affiliate Information</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

This will extend sales_order_columns and add a column based on affiliate_information filed, of type text, with translatable label “Affiliate Information”.

**Populating created sales_order_grid column for existing order**

For upgrading existing data either install (for first release of your module) or upgrade script should be created.

Here is an example of upgrade script populating `sales_order_grid.affiliate_information` column from `affiliate.affiliate_information` for **1.0.1 version of module**.

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $grid = $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid');
            $affiliate = $setup->getTable('affiliate');

            $connection->query(
                $connection->updateFromSelect(
                    $connection->select()
                        ->join(
                            $affiliate,
                            sprintf('%s.entity_id = %s.order_id', $grid, $affiliate),
                            'affiliate_information'
                        ),
                    $grid
                )
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

---

**For this upgrade script to be executed, you have to increase module version in module.xml `(from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1)`***

run `bin/magento setup:upgtade` command

Answer (score 1):

In your module extend `sales_order_grid.xml` file as:  `Vendor_Module::view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

Add the column in your `sales_order_grid` table of the database as per your requirement i.e `first_name` as per your requirement.. And then use the below code in your custom `sales_order_grid.xml` :

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="your namespace code" >
    <column name="first_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">First Name</label>
            </settings>
     </column>
</listing>
```

I have assumed that you have already created the column `first_name` in your database and have values in it. You just want to get that data in your sales order grid.